# Getting the parent organization unit (if any) of an organizational unit in Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I've created a small entity class:

```
public class OrganizationalUnit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ParentUO { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }    
}
```

Here's how I create objects of this type:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides an object that allows you to get organizational units within an 
    /// active directory domain.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connectionString">The LDAP connection string to a domain. 
    /// For example LDAP://DC=YourCompany,DC=com</param>
    public ActiveDirectoryOrganizationalUnitRepository(string connectionString, string username, string password)
    {
        organizationalUnits = new List<OrganizationalUnit>();

        if (DomainExists(connectionString))
        {
            var baseDirectory = new DirectoryEntry(connectionString);
            baseDirectory.Username = username;
            baseDirectory.Password = password;

            DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher();
            searcher.SearchRoot = baseDirectory;
            searcher.Filter = "(objectCategory=organizationalUnit)";
            searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

            var ouResults = searcher.FindAll();

            foreach (SearchResult ou in ouResults)
            {
                organizationalUnits.Add(new OrganizationalUnit() { 
                                        Path = ou.Path, 
                                        Name = ou.Properties["name"][0].ToString(),
                                        ParentUO = ou.Properties["parent"][0].ToString()}
                );                    
            }
        }        
    }
```

I need help filling the ParentOU property. I get a index out of range exception when trying to get it:

```
ParentUO = ou.Properties["parent"][0].ToString();
```

So this means, there is no property named 'parent'.

Any suggestions? I'd also like to find a list of properties that exist, but I've yet to find one online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First :**
From the pure Directory point of vue, you've got in your organizationalUnit (OU) an attribute called "`distinguishedName`" which looks like :

```
OU=currentOU,OU=parentOU,...,DC=domain,DC=..
```

so you can easily compute the string of the parent OU.

**Second :**
On the programming point of view, you've got a property of `DirectoryEntry` class which is `parent`. Here is a sample code.

```
String myADSPath = "LDAP://onecity/CN=user,CN=Users,DC=onecity,DC=corp,DC=fabrikam,DC=com";
DirectoryEntry myDirectoryEntry=new DirectoryEntry(myADSPath, UserName, SecurelyStoredPassword);

Console.WriteLine("Parent is :"+myDirectoryEntry.Parent.Path);
```

JP

Answer (score 0):

I found this code which lists all the properties a SearchResult object may have. It seems it doesn't list it's parent organizational unit.

```
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher();

searcher.SearchRoot = baseDirectory;
searcher.Filter = "(objectCategory=organizationalUnit)";
searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

var ouResults = searcher.FindAll();

foreach (SearchResult ou in ouResults)
{

    ResultPropertyCollection myResultPropColl;
    myResultPropColl = ou.Properties;
    Console.WriteLine("The properties of the " +
            "'mySearchResult' are :");

    foreach (string myKey in myResultPropColl.PropertyNames)
    {
        string tab = "    ";
        Console.WriteLine(myKey + " = ");
        foreach (Object myCollection in myResultPropColl[myKey])
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tab + myCollection);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [DirectoryEntry.Parent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.parent.aspx)?

The following code should work but I didn't try it.

```
organizationalUnits.Add(new OrganizationalUnit() { 
                                    Path = ou.Path, 
                                    Name = ou.Properties["name"][0].ToString(),
                                    ParentUO = ou.GetDirectoryEntry().Parent.Path}
```

There is no attribute called "Parent" on the organizationUnit class object.  Please check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683886%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for all the attributes on organizational-Unit.